# How to customize text and buttons for the About entry under the Help Menu in a Eclipse 3.8.1 RCP application

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-3.6

I am trying to customize the Help->About menu entry on Eclipse 3.8.1. I tried two 3.x friendly methods since Eclipse 4.0 works differently.

---> I tried extends the AboutAction itself (org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.AboutDialog) so I can add one line to the DialogArea Text and add a scrollable Dialog Gui when the License button is clicked.But all the methods are protected in the API I see it says user can use but not override (same with the Dialog class)

---> I tried extending the default AbstractHandler and in the execute method I am creating a Dialog object where I basically want to add all the things I need one by one. Only issue with that is that I can not work on the Dialog object in the execute method because it remains a null reference until the end of the execute method so I am not able to add things to it without the nullPointerException bugging me.

---> I also tried adding `<property>` to the plugin.xml itself. This seems to be a 4.x feature. description field under the about menu also did not work to write text in the About dialog text area

```
    @SuppressWarnings("restriction")
    public class AboutActionStableHandler extends AbstractHandler {

public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException 
{
    helpDialog = new AboutDialog(HandlerUtil.getActiveShellChecked(event));
    helpDialog.open();
    //helpDialog.getDialogArea(); 
    Shell aboutShell = helpDialog.getShell(); 
    aboutShell.setLayout(new GridLayout());
    Label version = new Label(aboutShell, SWT.NONE);
    version.setText(Platform.getProduct().getDefiningBundle().getVersion().toString());
    version.setLayoutData(GridDataBuilder.create().
    grabExcessHorizontalSpace(true).
    widthHint(500).
    heightHint(5).
    horizontalAlignment(SWT.FILL).build());
    return null;
}
```

So I end up getting this runtime error when i click on the about Gui
        `java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.magic.gui.commands.AboutActionStableHandler.execute(AboutActionStableHandler.java:28)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:290)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:508)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerService.executeCommand(HandlerService.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.SlaveHandlerService.executeCommand(SlaveHandlerService.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.ui.menus.CommandContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(CommandContributionItem.java:829)
    at org.eclipse.ui.menus.CommandContributionItem.access$19(CommandContributionItem.java:815)
    at org.eclipse.ui.menus.CommandContributionItem$5.handleEvent(CommandContributionItem.java:805)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4169)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3758)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2701)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2665)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2499)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:679)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:668)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at com.magic.rcp.Application.start(Application.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)`

Comment: You should be able to create a dialog in the Handler. It is not clear what you mean by the null pointer exception, show us the code you tried.

Comment: see edits above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `helpDialog.open()` displays the dialog and does not return until it is closed when it is to late to modify it.

You could call `helpDialog.create()` to just create the dialog, and call `open()` later.

**But** `AboutDialog` is an **internal** class attempting to modify it like this is violating the [Eclipse API Rules of Engagement](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-API-Use/index.html) which is why you have had to suppress the restriction warning. There is no way that the `AboutDialog` can be modified officially.  If you want a different about dialog you should really write your own dialog.